# looking for a python (pymongo) function to update a cell (in some circumstances) and send it to db

Tags: python, pandas, pymongo, updates

I have a data frame (using pandas - python) with more than 10,000 rows with about 10,000 users
and I want to update all columns for all users in which each cell is like this :

```json
{'P1': {'type': 'normal', 'priority': 2},
 'P2': {'type': 'normal', 'priority': 1}}
```

For some of them, `priority` is set to `1`, some set to `2`, some set to `3`.

I want to change `'priority': 1` to `'priority': 2`, for all users who have `'priority': 1`
and `'priority': 2` to `'priority': 3` for all users who have `'priority': 2`

how should I update this field (`priority`)?should I use `mycol.update_one()` or `mycol.update_many()` and how?
thanks

I did not try anything specific but I expect to have it updated and sent to DB by a function

Comment: Would you elaborate your data model a bit?  For example, what does a row in the `pd.DataFrame` represent?  How is a _"user"_ represented? Is `'P1'` a user?  what are the `pd.DataFrame` columns? ... What do they represent?  Is a _"cell"_ a specific row and column in the dataframe?  What is the relationship between the pandas dataframe and the MongoDB collection(s)?  Are you looking for a way to update the pandas dataframe and then update a MongoDB collection ... or just write a new collection with the contents of the updated dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple you have to use updates_many as you want to update all cell with specific location

```
for item in my_list:
    my_collection.update({"_id" : item[key] }, {'$inc': {'priority': 1}}, upsert=False))
```

Increment all priority with 1 so

**priority 1 became 2**

**priority 2 became 3**